# Django form not rendering properly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am following the documentation of the Django Forms but I do not know why my form does not want to show up ! 
I am creating a form that will get an email en create invitation for user to sign in using this app :https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations

My forms.py:

```
class InviteForm(forms.Form):
     email1 = forms.EmailField(label='Email 1')
```

My Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import InviteForm


class candidateIndex(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'candidateIndex.html'

class HRIndex(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'HRindex.html'

def create_invite(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InviteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            email = form.cleaned_data['email1']
            invite = Invitation.create('form.email1')
            invite.send_invitation(request)
            print("The mail was went")
        else:
            print("Your form is not valid")
    else:
       form = InviteForm()
    return render(request, 'HRindex.html', {'form': form})
```

My HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Welcome to SoftScores.com</h1>
  <h2>Team analytics platfom</h2>
  <h3>Welcome to {{user.username}}, it is your Page</h3>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Create a new team
    </a>
  </p>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
      In order to create a new team please invite new members. A link will be sent to them in order to give the access to the application
    </div>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

urls.py: 
from django.conf.urls import url
from website import views

app_name = 'website'

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^candidateIndex/$', views.candidateIndex.as_view(), name='candidate_index'),
    url(r'^HRIndex/$', views.HRIndex.as_view(), name='HR_index'),
]
```

When it render the page I get only the button but the form does not seems to work 
Do you habe any idea ?

Comment: #Irrelevant to question - `.is_valid` is a method, not an attribute.

Comment: What URL are you trying to view the form on? You have not shown the views `candidateIndex` or `HRIndex`, and there is no URL pattern for `CreateInvite`.

Comment: Be careful with your capitalization. `Email1` in the form does not match `form.cleaned_data['email1']`. And I would usually expect to see `{{ user. username }}` instead of `{{ User.username }}`. The normal approach in Django would be to name the field `email1`, the function based view `create_invite`, and the class based views `CandidateIndex` and `HRIndex`.

Comment: Thx Alasdair for your remarks, I modified the misCapitalisations. I want my form to be shown on the HRIndex.html page, what do you mean by CreateInvite URL pattern ? The weired thing is I do not even see the form on my page .. only the button ;(

Comment: The view that's rendering your form is `create_invite` (a function view) but you don't have a URL pattern using it. As @Alasdair asked, what URL are you entering in your browser expecting to see the form? You've defined 3 views in `views.py` but only have 2 URL patterns in `urls.py`.

Comment: As an aside, the line where you create the invite should probably be `invite = Invitation.create(email)`. `email = form.cleaned_data['email1']` on the previous line is the correct way to get the email from the form. Using `form.email1` is not valid, and `'form.email1'` is a string, not a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `HR_index` url is being handled by the `HRIndex` view, but this does not have any code to handle the form.

```
url(r'^HRIndex/$', views.HRIndex.as_view(), name='HR_index'),
```

Since a `TemplateView` is not really suited to handling a form, it would be better to modify the URL pattern to use the `create_invite` view instead:

```
url(r'^HRIndex/$', views.create_invite, name='HR_index'),
```

Comment: Alasdair, thx you very much ;) Can I ask you another question ? now when I post the form I get the error : name 'Invitation' is not defined. Invitation is an external that I installed using pip install ..

Comment: You need to import the model: `from invitations.models import Invitation`.

Comment: Alasdair how can I insert my form into other pages. I had a second thought and I need my users to create a project and then on the project detail page be able to create a team .. but my url look like that : url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='ProjectDetails'), How can I add it there as well . ? thx you ;)

Comment: That's a different problem, so it would be better to ask a new question.